# Switch HTML ID Attribute Value Between HTML Text-Boxes Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xhtml

I have stack of HTML Text-Boxes (More than 2) in my HTML Form. When the HTML Page loads for the 1st time  the ID attribute is empty. But when a user clicks on a text-box the ID should be "active". Others should be empty. When the user clicks on another, the previous text-box's id should be empty. The new text-box's id should be "active".

```
<input type="text" name="test" id="active">
<input type="text" name="test" id="">
<input type="text" name="test" id="">
<input type="text" name="test" id="">
<input type="text" name="test" id="">
<input type="text" name="test" id="">
```

How can I do this using JavaScript? Could you someone can help me to solve this matter?

Thanks and regards,
Chiranthaka.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, this is a pure javascript solution.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function changeIds(selectedEle)
{
    var elements = document.getElementsByName("test");
    for(var index = 0 ; index < elements.length ; index++ )
    {
        elements[index].id="";
    }
    selectedEle.id="active";
}


</script>
<body>
<form id="myForm" >
    <input type="text" onclick="changeIds(this)" name="test" id="active">
    <input type="text" onclick="changeIds(this)" name="test" id="">
    <input type="text" onclick="changeIds(this)" name="test" id="">
    <input type="text" onclick="changeIds(this)" name="test" id="">
    <input type="text" onclick="changeIds(this)" name="test" id="">
    <input type="text" onclick="changeIds(this)" name="test" id="">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using outdated `onclick=""` with creating six `onclick="changeIds(this)"` doesn't look good at all. There is [addEventListener()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp) for this.

Comment: There is a point in your comment but you have to scan all the element to attach event listeners. As well as if those elements are added programmatically then this is not a big issue.

Comment: Noone says it will work faster. The purpose is to remove duplicate code and to remove JS logic from HTML view (markup).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.focus()` to detect focus event on textbox along with `removeAttr()` and `.attr()` to set id to focused element:

```
$("[name='test']").focus(function() {
  $('#active').removeAttr('id');
  $(this).attr('id','active');
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j9kmpysk/)**

Comment: Let's just say that using class instead of ID with `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` will be more appropriate way.

Comment: he is keeping the ID to one element only. that way ID remains unique.

Comment: I have already deleted comment about unique ID, but the whole idea to use ID instead of class for this purpose looks "not good" for me. The easiest way to get problems with it: if there will be need to add `active` to one more element. Or another element with same styles on the page.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `class` attribute instead of the `id` attribute. So you can do something like this:

```
var inputs = $('input[type="text"]');
inputs.click(function(){
    inputs.removeClass(active);
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: `$('input[name="test"]')` will be more precise, but +1.

Comment: Mhm your question has an `jQuery` tag ;-)